# Mapbox Leaflet - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setGeoJSON' of undefined

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I try to set Geojson layer on my map, using geojson and mapbox leaflet. here is the code of my map :

```
function grabTravelData(travel_id) {
    url: '/' + travel_id + '/show.json'
}
$(function(){
    var travel_map = L.mapbox.map('travel_map').setView([45.52086, -122.679523], 14)
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=<access_token>')
        .addTo(travel_map);


    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()

    function _fetchGeojson() {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: grabTravelData(),
            success: function(data) {
                var geojson = data;
                travel_map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);

            }
        });
    }

    _fetchGeojson();
});
```

But when I go to my page I have this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setGeoJSON' of undefined
```

It seems to be featureLayer that is undefined, but i don't understand why, I read mapbox.js documentation and I follow there instructions to do that,

Can someone should help me ?

Comment: What's the value of `travel_map.featureLayer` in your `travel_map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);` line? Use the debugging tools of your web browser to set a breakpoint there and inspect the value.

Comment: @IvanSanchez i used debbuger and when I do `console.log(travel_map.featureLayer)` I have `undefined`

Comment: What did you expect that to be? Are you using that in some other part of the code?